# php execute shell commands, dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, shell-exec

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf executable to convert some html to pdf. I'm just testing it out on my mac and if I run the executable via terminal it works fine. If I run it using php shell_exec I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
>   Reason: Incompatible library version:
>   DictionaryServices requires version
>   10.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 9.0.0

If I spit out the cmd that I'm using via php I can run it and it works fine in the terminal.

I think it's a pathing issue, so I echoed out my users path which was different than the paths avialble to php, so I added it to the command before:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin; ./wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368 ./'newxhtml.html' /tmp_pdf.pdf
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks,  MS

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was going on.

First to trouble shoot I ran the command:

env

From both my terminal and my php secript.

I noticed in my php script that it had the following explicitly set:

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path

But in the terminal that value wasn't set at all. So all I did was add:

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="";

Here's my final command:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="";./wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368 ./'newxhtml.html' ./tmp_pdf.pdf 2>&1

And I just run it via shell_exec.